# Why Vector2 (from XNA's library) uses float not int?

Tags: xna, floating-point, int, draw, spritebatch

Why **Vector2** (from XNA's library) uses **float** not **int**?

Position on computer screen is given in pixels so that cursor position can be defined by two **int**egers. There is no such a thing like *half a pixel*. Why we use floats then?

In **SpriteBatch** class I've found 7 overloaded methods called **Draw**. Two of them:

```cs
public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Rectangle destinationRectangle, Color color);
public void Draw(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, Color color);
```

So we can see that **Draw** accepts both **int** and **float** coordinates.

I came across this problem when I've been implementing screen coordinates of my game's objects. I assumed that **Rectangle** is good choice to hold object's size and screen coordinates. But now I'm not sure...

Comment: When you're working with scalars, always use decimal numbers. or if you have a speed at 0.1f, and you keep adding it to a int, the position will remain the same. But with a float this will make your position keep increasing.

Comment: @patryk  -The Vector2 is used for so many other things besides simply screen pixel positions. Most of the other uses involve arithmetic where precision finer than whole numbers is desired.

Comment: Also, using `Draw(Texture2D, Rectangle, Color)` you can 'scale' texture to destination rectangle, but `Draw(Texture2D, Vector2D, Color)` will use `Texture2D`s `.Width` and `.Height`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematically, a vector is a motion, not a position. While a position on the screen might not technically be able to be between integers, a motion definitely can. If a vector used `int`s then the slowest you could move would be `(1, 1)`. With `float`s you can move `(.1, .1)`, `(.001, .001)`, and so on.

(Notice also that the XNA struct `Point` does actually use `int`s.)

Answer (score 4):

You could use both `Vector2` and `Rectangle` to represent your objects coordinates. I usually do it like this:

```
public class GameObject
{
    Texture2D _texture;

    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; } //doesn't have to be private
    public int Height { get; private set; } //but it's nicer when it doesn't change :)

    public Rectangle PositionRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, Width, Height);
        }
    }

    public GameObject(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this._texture = texture;
        this.Width = texture.Width;
        this.Height = texture.Height;
    }
}
```

To move objects, just set their `Position` property to a new value.

```
_player.Position = new Vector2(_player.Position.X, 100);
```

You don't have to worry about the rectangle, as it's value depends directly on `Position`.

My game objects also usually contain methods to draw themselves, such as

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(this._texture, this.Position, Color.White);
}
```

Collision detection code in your `Game.Update()` could just use the `PositionRectangle` to test for collisions

```
//_player and _enemy are of type GameObject (or one that inherits it)
if(_player.PositionRectangle.Intersects(_enemy.PositionRectangle))
{
    _player.Lives--;
    _player.InvurnerabilityPeriod = 2000;
    //or something along these lines;
}
```

You could also call the `spriteBatch.Draw()` with `PositionRectangle`, you shouldn't notice much difference.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* such a thing as "half a pixel."  Using float coordinates that aren't pixel-aligned will cause your sprites to be rendered at sub-pixel coordinates.  This is often necessary to make objects appear to scroll smoothly, but it can also produce an unpleasant shimmering effect in some circumstances.

See here for a summary of the basic idea: [Subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering)

Comment: So what structure should I use to remember object's size (in __float__) and screen coordinates (also __float__). **Rectangle** would be perfect but it uses __int__. I'm looking for __float__ **Rectangle** equivalent without creating my own structure (I don't want to reinvent the wheel if you know what I mean;)).

Comment: In my 2D games I generally just use Vector2 for position and a Rectangle for bounding, as Niko Drašković described in his answer.